# Expanding nested container to page width

Tags: css

I have a DIV with a fixed width of the 960px and nested containers with no specific width so they stretches to parent container. Is it possible, without removing the outer container, to stretch inner container to full page width, in the same time, content should be as wide as outer container.

A little example:

```
+------------------------------------------------+  
|                      browser window (100%)     |
|                                                |
|     +-----------------------------------+      | 
|     | (A)     inner container (960px)   |      | 
|     |                                   |      | 
|*****|***********************************|******| 
|     |  (B)                              |      | 
|     |                                   |      | 
|     |  this should stretch to 100% of   |      | 
|     |   body and have inner width of    |      | 
|     |     of 960px (or the same as      |      | 
|     |         closest parent)           |      | 
|     |                                   |      | 
|*****|***********************************|******| 
|     |                                   |      | 
|     +-----------------------------------+      | 
|                                                | 
+------------------------------------------------+
```

The reasoning behind this is i have to specify some background of the block, but i have problems in case if i remove the outer container which specifies a fixed width.

Update: the inner container (B) should be inside (A) like this:

```
<div class="container" style="width:960px">
       <div class="box">
            This box should stretch to 100% of page and must have non-fixed height.
       </div>
</div>
```

There should be multiple containers on the page, some of them should stretch, some not. Absolute positioning breaks the normal flow of the document and subsequent containers are overlapped with previous.

Answer (score 1):

You could use position absolute

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/C8tnP/2/

```
.box {
    background:#ccc;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, this is a little bit harder, i updated the question to clarify.

Comment: If i put multiple containers one after another, they are not stacked with absolute positioning :(

Answer (score 1):

For each element involved, add this to its CSS:

'box-sizing: border-box;'

Be sure to add vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways for doing this:

1. Your 100%-width element should be a children of `<body>`, then inside it, specify again that container of 960px. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqS9X/)
2. Use that 100%-width element as an absolute element. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsktZ/)

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot go out of the parent container that specifies fixed width, and the second approach breaks the flow of the document, and everything after the absolute-positioned box does not appear directly after it.